# How to change the text of multiple labels using a loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to change labels in an asp.net web form. My label IDs are lbl1, lbl2, lb3, etc.

```vb
    con.Open()
    For i = 1 To 6
        SQL = "SELECT Question FROM Question WHERE TestID=" & Session("TestID") & " AND QuestionID=" & Convert.ToString(i) & ";"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, con)
        Dim myControl As Control = FindControl("ContentHolder_" & "lbl" & Convert.ToString(i))
        myControl.Text() = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    Next
    con.Close()
```

This obviously doesn't work as .Text is not a property of myControl.
I couldn't work out how to work around this problem.

p.s. I inspected the element of the label in google chrome and found out that it has ContentHolder_ before the name I gave in the id of the element. This is because I use a masterpage and thats why it is there.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

`Control` is a base class of all types of webform controls. You need to use the specific type of control you are using. For example, if it is a `<asp:Label>` control, you need to use the `Label` type instead of the `Control` type. Like this:

```
Dim myControl As Label = CType(FindControl("ContentHolder_" & "lbl" & 
    Convert.ToString(i)), Label)
myControl.Text = "whatever"
```

There is a second thing wrong with your code, however. You are putting your SQL query in a loop. You should always try to reduce the number of round trips to your database. In this case, that means changing your code to query the database once, and then using an `OleDbDataReader` to read the data back. Your code will perform much faster that way.

Comment: Thanks very much for the tips! Unfortunately this code doesn't work and I tried declaring it as label which was the sensible thing at first but it would give this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Also when I look at locals, myControl comes as Nothing. I am not sure where the problem is...